# Estimating precision of matlabs matrix solver

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, matlab, numerical-linear-algebra

I'm interested in determining the precision of the matrix solution using matlabs "x = A\b" solver.

The "A" I am working with is a non-singular, symmetric n x n matrix (that is typically 100x100, but I am interested in the general case). Elements in this matrix are either 0 or some number between 10^-8 and 10^-4. There are typically around 7n non-zero elements (3n in upper diagonal, 3n in lower diagonal, all diagonal elements are non-zero).

The "b" I am working with is a vector of length n with all elements zero except one or two elements which are numbers between -5 and 5 (of some arbitrary order of magnitude).

Does anyone have any ideas of where I can look or a method that I could use to calculate this?

I haven't been able to find the details of what is behind the hood of the default MATLAB solver

Comment: Some information about the method used by Matlab's backslash operator can be found in the Matlab documentation here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html If I understand this correctly, then for square dense matrices with no additional structure Matlab uses Matlab's [LU solver](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/lu.html), which uses a variant of Gaussian elimination.

Comment: The LU documentation notes that, "Computing an accurate solution is dependent upon the value of the condition number of the original matrix `cond(A)`. If the matrix has a large condition number (it is nearly singular), then the computed factorization might not be accurate." So the precision depends on the condition number of your matrix.

Comment: You want to solve the system of linear equation, right? You can use many method to find the solution. You can use inverse method like you say in your question, you can use LU decomposition, jacobian iteration, etc.

Comment: Thanks @littleO . Condition was what I was looking for